# What are the best practises to decide whether a variable is categorical?

Tags: data-cleaning, categorical-data, structured-data

What are some of the systematic ways to categorise variables into categorical or numeric? I believe using only intuition in such scenarios can many-a-times lead to major irreversible errors. What are the best strategies when categorising variables?

For example, the dataframe I'm working has several categorical variables such as `is_holiday` that has labels for several holidays. However certain variables like `visibility_in_miles` suggest that those too need to be treated as categorical. part of the reason is that while most variables have hundreds of unique values, some have only 9 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of categories within a variable does not matter whether a variable is categorical or not.

Categorical variables are mutually exclusive, unordered groups. For example, Christmas and Halloween are different holidays but have no order in the concept of "holiday-ness".

Ordinal variables which are mutually exclusive, ordered groups with no consistent measure of the distance between the ordering. For example, ranking items (e.g., first, second, third, …). There could be big (or small) differences between each of the places.

Numeric variables have consistent differences between values. The difference between 10 and 11 miles is the same as the difference 20 and 21 miles because "mile-ness" is a consistent measure.

Comment: So would you suggest that `dew_point` for example, that has only values from 1 to 9 would be categorical since it suggests that there is no order and are mutually exclusive values?

Comment: I don't what is `dew_point` in your data set. If it is dew point temperature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point, that is numeric because it is measured in degrees. Temperature degrees have consent differences (regardless of range).